# SQLServer update set only when value has changed

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have read many answers to this question that say it doesn't really matter if you update a column that hasn't changed but it can do and I wonder if there is a decent solution.

We have an update proc that updates all the fields on a record - some of them possibly to the same value that they currently are.

The issue we have is that we have an indexed view where this table is a parent to many thousands of child records and some of this tables fields are in that indexed view. Every time we do an update, even if it is effectively unchanged, it still does a lot of work in maintaining that indexed view.

I want to be able to do an UPDATE SET and have some way of only setting if there value is different. Not a where clause because I still want the other fields updated.

I guess Entity Framework does something like this in creating a dynamic update statement? Is there a simple solution for ADO.NET users using a stored proc for an update?

tia

Comment: I'm failing to see why the index would need to be rebuilt if you update a value to the same thing?  Surely the index would stay the same in that case.  If you update a value to something else then possibly the index will also need to be updated.  I think you are shooting for something that won't improve your system.

Comment: try creating a parent and child table and then an indexed view containing one or two of the parent table's fields. Create say a 1000 child rows for a single parent. If you then do an update of the parent table setting those fields to the same, you will see in the explain plan, quite a big workload on the indexed view. Now just update the parent table but without setting those view fields. We have parent rows with 50000-100000 child rows which is causing a major headache when updating the parent row even though the relevant fields have not changed

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code, it's kind of hard to see what you currently are doing, but I'd include something like a `WHERE table.value != newValue`.

I.e.

```
UPDATE myTargetTable
SET myTargetTable.myColumn = mySourceTable.newValue 
FROM mySourceTable JOIN myTargetTable on mySourceTable.ID = myTargetTable.ID
WHERE myTargetTable.myColumn != mySourceTable.newValue
```

Comment: "Not a where clause because I still want the other fields updated" would seem to rule this out.

Comment: Hmm. I missed that bit of the post.

Comment: yes unfortunately that isn't any good when you are updating 5 fields bu actually only 2 of them have changed.